# Show chosen menu item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, menu, menuitem

Hy,

I have a menu with a few menu items. I have various other elements like a treeview and some controls. When I open the program all elements in the menu are available. But the first step I have to do is to connect to the server. So all the the other elements shouldn't available till there is made a connection via the connection menu item.

Then I want to show only menu items if a special tree view (for instance the whole item structure) item is choosen for instance all topics. For instance there should be special menu items available if I click a treeview entry in the menu.

Is it possible to accomplish this in xaml?

**Update1:**

MainWindow.xaml

```
Title="Service Bus Visualizer" Height="680" Width="1200" Name="Root"
<MenuItem Header="_Read File" Name="readFile" Click="MenuItemReadFile" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="187" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsMonitoring, ElementName=Root}">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="Icons/Open.ico" Width="16" Height="16" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public bool IsMonitoring
{
    get
    {
        return isMonitoring;
    }
    set
    {
        isMonitoring = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsMonitoring");
    }
}

private bool isMonitoring;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.IsMonitoring = false;
    this.DataContext = this;
    Application.Current.MainWindow = this;
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

ConnectionWindow.xaml.cs

```
MainWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
mainWindow.IsMonitoring = true;
```

I get no error on the output window but it doesn't work?

**Update2:**

I have a second parameter which is a ObservableCollection.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="3" Name="Logger" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.LoggingList, ElementName=Root}" DisplayMemberPath="Message" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectionChanged="BringSelectionIntoView">
</ListBox>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public static ObservableCollection<Log> LoggingList { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    LoggingList = new ThreadSafeObservableCollection<Log>();
    this.IsMonitoring = false;
    this.DataContext = this;
    Application.Current.MainWindow = this;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Log.cs

```
public class Log : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Message {
        get
        {
            return message;
        }
        set
        {
            message = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Message");
        }
    }
    public string message;

    public Log()
    {
    }

    public Log(string message)
    {
        this.Message = message;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Message");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }        
}
```

Best regards

Comment: If by "in XAML" you mean "through bindings to the view model" then yes, you can definitely accomplish this. Is that what you meant?

Comment: hy, yes do you have an example to show me how this works?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have two options as far as "availability" is concerned. The "IsEnabled" property, and the "Visible" property. "IsEnabled" is a bool, and determines if the user can click/select/interact with a given element. Generally speaking, if this property is set to false the element will appear "greyed out".

Changing Visibility will make the element appear/disappear entirely. When set to "Visible" (this is actually an enum), it appears normally. When set to "Hidden", the space for it is reserved on the UI, but you can't actually see it. When set to "Collapsed" you cannot see it and no space is reserved for it in the layout.

For your first requirement (waiting to connect to the server), I would use IsEnabled bound to a "IsConnected" property like so:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding IsConnected}"
```

That would go on each item that needs to have this behavior.

The "context-specific" menu items are a bit more complicated, but the basic idea would be a binding on Visible for each of the context sensitive items like:

```
Visible="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=MyTreeView, Converter={StaticResource SelectedItemToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Type ChildItem}"
```

I am assuming that each items visibility depends on what type of item is selected (child or parent), you should be able to extend the example if I was wrong. The converter would then look like:

```
public class SelectedItemToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((parameter as Type).IsInstanceOfType(value))
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(...)
    {
         return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I can clarify anything. Hopefully that gives you a good starting point for what you are trying to do.

**Update:**

Looking at your code I see a couple potential problems:

1. `IsMonitoring` is declared as a public field. Binding only works with public properties. This property needs to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for it to work.
2. In "MainWindow.xaml.cs" you are setting the DataContext multiple times. This isn't how DataContext works in WPF. You need to set it to one object (your ViewModel) that contains all the properties you are interested in binding to. While it is considered bad practice, you could write `this.DataContext = this` to get it working before you build a ViewModel class.
3. The `IsMonitoring` field is declared in your "MainWindow.xaml.cs" file. First, this should be in a view model. Second, the binding is looking for that property on the `MenuItem` class (likely because it is in some sort of ItemsControl). If you want it on the root data context, give your window some name (like "Root") and use the following binding:

   ```
   "{Binding Path=DataContext.IsMonitoring, ElementName=Root}"
   ```

Hopefully that makes sense. Let me know if I can help further!

Comment: Hy, sorry for the late response. I tried it but it didn't work. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong with the Binding because it always says in the output window BindingExpression path error. I added the example in the first post.

Comment: Your code isn't quite set up right for bindings, see my comments. I'm sure we can get it working though!

Comment: Hy, thank you for the perfect description. I tried it but it doesn't work. I updated above in the main post the Example. It would be great if you can tell what I did wrong.

Comment: First, try setting a breakpoint on the getter of your property (that will tell you the binding is actually working) and make sure it is returning the correct value. You may need to use x:Name instead of Name for the binding to work correctly. Other than that it looks fine, I'll keep looking and let you know if I see anything. Also note that you set it to false in your constructor, then straight to true. I would expect that the checkbox is enabled in this case (is that what you are seeing?)

Comment: Hy, ok in the beginning when I start the application it jumps in the getter. If I write at the beginning `private bool isMonitoring = true;` it activates the menu item, so the binding works fine. I think the problem is in the setter. When I set the value it calls the method `this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsMonitoring");`. But in there it don't jumps into the if because the ProbertyChanged proberty is Null. The only thing I didn't do was to inherit the `...Window : INotifyPropertyChanged` because it didn't work in the main xaml.cs file, why? Should I give the ProbertyChanged somewhere a value?

Comment: It jumps only at the beginning when i start the program in the getter, later when the setter calls it never jumps in the getter.

Best regards

Comment: You absolutely have to inherit INotifyPropertyChanged for this to work! It will work fine in Main.Xaml.cs (though as you probably know, it should be a view model instead). Even if you raise the event, not inheriting from the interface will break your binding updates.

Comment: Hy, thank you now it works. But I have a ObservableCollection in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file but now the binding doesn't work. I added an Update2 in the main post. It would be great if can help me again with the problem.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? The code looks fine at first glance. You aren't adding anything to the collection, so nothing will appear in your ListBox, but otherwise it should be ok. Note that if your listbox doesn't have a special data context (ie in a items control) you can do a normal binding without the ElementName trick. That wouldn't cause anything to break though.

Comment: Hy, now I got it. In the Constructor the order wasn't correct. I added the correct initalization of the constructo in the main post.Thank you very much for your help.